# Entity Framework 7 and SQLite Tables not creating

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I've been trying for awhile to figure out how to use a single DBContext to create multiple tables in a Code First fashion without any luck. I'm sure it's just my unfamiliarity with the framework but I'm not sure what I'm missing. Here's a simple example with entities and the DBContext.

```
[Table("MyEntity")]
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string MyColumn { get; set; }
    public int MyNumber { get; set; }
}

[Table("MySecondEntity")]
public class MySecondEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string MyColumn { get; set; }
    public int MyNumber { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyTable { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MySecondEntity> MyTable2 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder {DataSource = "test.db"};
        var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();
        var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connection);
    }
}
```

It looks to me like it should work, but when I call it in the below code it blows up with a 'no such table: MyEntity' Sqlite exception when hitting the first foreach loop.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {

            MyEntity testEntity1 = new MyEntity();
            MySecondEntity entity1 = new MySecondEntity();

            testEntity1.MyColumn = "Test Data 1";
            testEntity1.MyNumber = 12345;

            db.MyTable.Add(testEntity1);
            db.Database.Migrate();

            entity1.MyColumn = "New Data 1";
            entity1.MyNumber = 2;

            db.MyTable2.Add(entity1);
            db.Database.Migrate();

            Console.WriteLine("Inserting Data...");

            Console.WriteLine("Data in the Database");

            foreach (var entity in db.MyTable)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Id: " + entity.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Column Data: " + entity.MyColumn);
                Console.WriteLine("Number: " + entity.MyNumber);
            }

            foreach (var entity in db.MyTable2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Id: " + entity.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Column Data: " + entity.MyColumn);
                Console.WriteLine("Number: " + entity.MyNumber);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Examples run finished,press Enter to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I can almost guarantee it's something simple I'm missing but I just can't seem to find it, and there aren't any examples I can find in their documentation. There seems to be a similar issue submitted on GitHub here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2874 but that's for multiple contexts. So maybe this is another piece that just hasn't quite made it to release yet?

**Solution**

By following the tutorial posted on http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/uwp.html as suggested by @natemcmaster and the solution recommended by @lukas-kabrt I was able to get it to work as desired. By running the below commands I was able to get the tables created and insert/select data from them.

```
Install-Package EntityFramework.Commands –Pre
Add-Migration MyFirstMigration
Update-Database
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DbContext` class contains configuration of your database - tables, relationsships, etc. To use the `DbContext` you need to create a database that matches your `DbContext`. In the Code-first world, it is done by database migrations.

For **ASP.NET 5** you need to add this configuration to your `project.json` file

```
"commands": {
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
}
```

and then add a migration to your project and apply this migration to the DB by running following commands

```
dnx ef migrations add MyFirstMigration
dnx ef database update
```

For **Full .NET** you need to run following commands in the *Package Manager Console* (Tools ‣ NuGet Package Manager ‣ Package Manager Console)

```
Install-Package EntityFramework.Commands –Pre
Add-Migration MyFirstMigration
Update-Database
```

Comment: Thanks @lukas-kabrt in the actual WPF application that this needs to go into we don't have a package.json file. Does this just go in the project root or where the app.xaml is located? Also, this is being distributed through an msi installer, is there a way to run those commands without having to use the command line and just have it done through code?

Comment: to add to this, if on ASP.NET Core, use dotnet instead of dnx on the CLI.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Getting Started on UWP  - EF 7](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/uwp.html) in the official docs. The following notes are from that document.

The default path on UWP is not writable. Your DB file needs to be in `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`

```
options.UseSqlite("Data Source=" + Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "blogging.db"))
```

Also, take note that on UWP you cannot run migrations from commands. You need to run them in the app.

```
       using (var db = new BloggingContext())
        {
            db.Database.Migrate();
        }
```

Comment: This helped out a lot! It seems to do exactly what I need it to!